# access plist data

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, plist

i have a plist which goes like this:

```
 <dict>  
   <key>11231654</key>
  <array>
      <string>hello</string>
      <string>goodbye</string>
  </array>
  <key>78978976</key>
  <array>
        <string>ok</string>
    <string>cancel</string>
   </array>
```

i've load the plist using this:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                    @"data" ofType:@"plist"];
    // Build the array from the plist  
    NSMutableArray *array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

how can i access each element of my plist?
i want to search for a matching key in the plist and than search with its child. how can i do this? any suggestion?

thks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

Arrays are indexed. If you wanted to access the first object in an `NSArray`, you’d do the following:

```
id someObject = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

If you know the object type, you could do it like this:

```
NSString *myString = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

---

**EDIT:** You need to use an `NSDictionary` for the data that you have—note that it starts with a `<dict>` tag, not an `<array>` tag (though there are arrays as values).

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                @"data" ofType:@"plist"];
// Build the array from the plist  
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSArray *value = [dict valueForKey:@"11231654"];
```

Now you can do whatever you want with your array.

Comment: how can i access the index value? 11231654 in this example

Comment: In that case, your data should be loaded into an `NSDictionary`. I’ll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911688/setting-up-a-plist-to-store-application-data-not-settings-for-an-iphone-game) is a link to a discussion that provided a very good example of how to access your data and which type of storage schemes would be more beneficial under certain circumstances.   @Jeff Kelley's solution is on target, I just thought this question would add an additional resource.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you need to create plist

[image: plist screenshot]

Set root to array instead of dictionary , this will give you results in sequence. 
With below lines of code you can fetch complete plist.

```
NSString *pathOfPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
arrPlistValue = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSLog(@"Plist Value : %@",arrPlistValue);
```

After that you can fetch any specific content with below code:

```
NSString *strName = [[arrTempValue objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *strImage = [[arrTempValue objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"image"];
int idValue = [[[arrTempValue objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
BOOL isSubCat = [[[arrTempValue objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"isSubCategory"] boolValue];
```

With this code you can fetch integer , string , boolean from plist.!